# Best way of relation database design in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, primary-key

i'm quite familiar with MySQL DBMS. I'm interested to know the best way to design more complicated 
relational database. Like, Lets say i have a "users" table with Auto Increment value which is "Primary Key".
Using this "PK" as "Foreign Key" i can create a table called "user_details" where i can store all confidential data of users.

Yes this is a good way to do it. But i wanted to know if there is any complicated way to do it.
Because if any body in localhost get access to database, they can easily get the "user_details" data based on users "PK".

Also, is it good idea to use application generated unique codes as a "PK" and "FK" in database Or Auto Increment value within database is more than enough?

Comment: This smells a little of an XY problem. If you're worried about people getting access, then either secure the server/don't give "anybody" access to the database (allow only certain processes running as a certain user access), or encrypt your data and don't give users the key.

Comment: @lc. Yes, We can build a tight security around database. Even for a second i got any idea of data encryption. Later i thought it may cause some performance issue. But i'm curious to know how huge relational databases are designed? Based on "auto increment" values itself? If you have some idea, Please share your knowledge :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a very vague questions, so I'll just list a few points:

- Your data model should not be concerned with server security.  Build your data model accurately for your application and lock down access to the db and tables as much as possible.  These are separate concerns.
- Use encryption for data that only the end user is allowed to know.  Passwords, for example, get one-way encryption.
- MySQL's auto increment is sufficient for most use cases.  The only time I sometimes have the application generate IDs is on [multi-master replicated databases](http://docforge.com/wiki/Programming_for_database_replication) where I need more centralized control or have unique requirements.  This isn't always necessary since you can set the autoincrement starting number separately for each server and not worry about the servers generating conflicting IDs.  There is sometimes a performance drawback to generating your own IDs, e.g. generating a GUID takes longer than incrementing an integer.